# Is the use of "am" in this sentence correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, ellipsis

Can I use **am** as written in this sentence below?

> I **am** certain that I can make a positive contribution to the
> Medical Enterprise Center at the Downers Hospital, given my diverse background, and
> **am** sure that a rich exchange will take place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separation between "I" and the second "am" is too great in this case, in my opinion. It is not exactly wrong but it feels strained.

Either use "I'm" or write "I am" in full.